# uitableview header background not shown until scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I used the following code to set the header view of a uitableview section. The problem is, the background color (mainLightColor_2) doesn't show up until I scroll the tableview. How can I make the background color shown on load?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 24)];
  headerView.backgroundColor = [Utility mainLightColor_2]; //mainLightColor is a blue color

  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 200, 20)];
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  label.textColor = [Utility mainDarkColor];
  label.text = @"Past Activities";
  [headerView addSubview:label];

  return headerView;
}
```

Before scroll:
[image: Before scroll]

After scroll:
[image: After scroll]

Comment: Try setting `label.opaque = NO;`

Comment: Just tried your code and it runs fine, maybe the problem is with the **[Utility mainLightColor_2]** method, try substituting it with **[UIColor blueColor]** just for testing and see what happens.

Comment: Can you try to post the Utility class code?

Comment: @MariamN. That didn't work either.

Comment: What iOS version are you testing on? Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @MariamN.I'm testing on 6.0. Not using storyboard.

Comment: @MariamN.I found a solution. Please see the answer. Still don't understand why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution to this. However, I still don't understand why setting the background color of headerView doesn't work.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 24)];

  UIView *headerViewBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 24)];
  headerViewBackground.backgroundColor = [Utility mainLightColor_2];
  [headerView addSubview:headerViewBackground];

  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 200, 20)];
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  label.textColor = [Utility mainDarkColor];
  label.text = @"Past Activities";
  [headerView addSubview:label];

  return headerView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Got a similar problem on iOS 8 where inserting a header doesn't show its background colour until you scroll it and doesn't show its alpha value until it goes off the screen and back on again. This work around sorts it.

Answer (score 1):

You should also implement `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 24;
}
```

Comment: I implemented that method.